# How can I create windows near by in tmux

Tags: tmux

Suppose I have 7 windows, and I am in the no.3. 
When I use `Ctrl+B c`, I create windows in the location 7. 
How can I create it in location 4 so that I was near the No.3?
Of course, the windows number after will also add its number with 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `new-window` function (to which <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> is bound), adding a **`-a`** option, e.g.,

```
bind-key -c C new-window -a
```

makes <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> create a new window after the current one (rather than at the end of the list).

The [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) is a little obscure (it helps to read the source-code):

> new-window [**`-adkP`**] [**`-c`** *start-directory*] [**`-F`** format] [**`-n`** *window-name*]
>   [**`-t`** *target-window*] [*shell-command*]
>   (alias: **`neww`**)
>   Create a new window.  With **`-a`**, the new window is inserted at
>   the next index up from the specified *target-window*, moving windows up if necessary, otherwise *target-window* is the new window
>   location.
>
> If **`-d`** is given, the session does not make the new window the
>   current window.  *target-window* represents the window to be created; if the target already exists an error is shown, unless
>   the **`-k`** flag is used, in which case it is destroyed.
>   shell-command is the command to execute.  If *shell-command* is
>   not specified, the value of the default-command option is used.
>   **`-c`** specifies the working directory in which the new window is
>   created.

The source-code (`cmd-find.c`) gives the clue in [`cmd_find_target`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/cmd-find.c#L984) that omitting the `-t` option is the way to go:

```
/* An empty or NULL target is the current. */
if (target == NULL || *target == '\0')
    goto current;
```

Comment: what does the ```-c``` part of ```bind-key``` do? I can't find it in the 3.1b manpage. In the 3.1b manpage I only see ```bind-key [-nr] [-N note] [-T key-table]```

Comment: According to the git-log, the developer removed `-c` (coincidence?) the day before my answer. and later removed mention from the manual page.